# Getting "Caught exception while attempting to handle SSO callback!" while setting SSO in Datahub

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-eks

I have installed Datahub application in a private EKS cluster using [this helm chart](https://github.com/acryldata/datahub-helm). Now I am trying to set SSO integration via Azure AD in the same Datahub application by following [this link](https://datahubproject.io/docs/authentication/guides/sso/configure-oidc-react-azure).

I followed all the steps as it is. But when I tried to login via SSO, then it redirects to that Azure AD SSO url and it says my user is logged in inside Azure AD portal but after that it gives below error in the Datahub pod logs:

**ERROR controllers.SsoCallbackController - Caught exception while attempting to handle SSO callback!**

Here is the OIDC config I used:

```
  oidcAuthentication:
      enabled: true
      provider: "azure"
      clientId: "client-id"
      clientSecretRef:
        secretRef: secret-name
        secretKey: secret-key
      scope: "openid profile email"
      azureTenantId: "azure-tenant-id"
    extraEnvs:
      - name: AUTH_VERBOSE_LOGGING
        value: "true"
```

Any Idea where I am doing wrong ?